# VBA If function with date and text

Tags: excel, vba, date

```
Sub SetFormulasFormat()
 
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim cl As Range

With ActiveSheet      
For Each cl In Application.Intersect(.Columns("E"), .UsedRange)
    If UCase(cl.Value) = "1ST" Then
```

I want to check if in column C the date is a weekday and use this in the if but nothing seems to work.
I tried

```
If UCase(cl.Value) = "1ST" AND Weekday(cl.Offset(, 2).Value, vbMonday) <6
```

Then but here I get an error

Can someone help me please? :-)

Comment: Use `Weekday(cl.Offset(, 2), vbMonday) < 6 Then`

Comment: Then I get an Type Mismatch error.

Comment: IF `cl` refers to column `E`, and your dates are in column `C`, maybe you want `Weekday(cl.Offset(, -2).Value)`

Comment: Still get the same error.

Comment: Then maybe your dates are not real dates. Or could be some other error relating to your data

Comment: But they are real dates.

Comment: You have not provided enough detail for me to offer any other suggestions. In accordance with forum guidelines, I suggest you create an example with data that would allow someone to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hi sorry Ron. I posted more info underneath. Hoping you can help me further :-)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Excelfile]

So this is my file. I have this for all the days of the week in one sheet.

What I want to do is use conditional formatting in the rows of 1ST,CUCA,SERVICE ADMIN,2ND,CHAT. This I have figured out but now I want this to only apply on monday to thursday and then other rules for friday, saturday, sunday.

So this is the code I have for the moment

```
Sub SetFormulasFormat()
```

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim cl As Range
With ActiveSheet

```
For Each cl In Application.Intersect(.Columns("E"), .UsedRange)
  
    If UCase(cl.Value) = "1ST" And Weekday(cl.Offset(, -2), vbMonday) < 6 Then
        .Range("F" & cl.Row).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=1" 'apply CF rule to 1 single cell in same row
        .Range("F" & cl.Row).FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbRed
        
        .Range("G" & cl.Row & ",H" & cl.Row & ",Y" & cl.Row).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=3" 'apply CF rule to 2 different cells in same row (Separate each cell with , like G2,H2...)
        .Range("G" & cl.Row & ",H" & cl.Row & ",Y" & cl.Row).FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbRed
        
        .Range("I" & cl.Row & ",J" & cl.Row & ",K" & cl.Row & ",L" & cl.Row & ",M" & cl.Row & ",N" & cl.Row & ",O" & cl.Row & ",P" & cl.Row & ",Q" & cl.Row & ",R" & cl.Row & ",S" & cl.Row & ",T" & cl.Row & ",U" & cl.Row & ",V" & cl.Row & ",W" & cl.Row & ",X" & cl.Row).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=4" 'apply CF rule to 2 different cells in same row (Separate each cell with , like G2,H2...)
        .Range("I" & cl.Row & ",J" & cl.Row & ",K" & cl.Row & ",L" & cl.Row & ",M" & cl.Row & ",N" & cl.Row & ",O" & cl.Row & ",P" & cl.Row & ",Q" & cl.Row & ",R" & cl.Row & ",S" & cl.Row & ",T" & cl.Row & ",U" & cl.Row & ",V" & cl.Row & ",W" & cl.Row & ",X" & cl.Row).FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbRed

        .Range("I" & cl.Row & ",J" & cl.Row & ",K" & cl.Row & ",L" & cl.Row & ",M" & cl.Row & ",N" & cl.Row & ",O" & cl.Row & ",P" & cl.Row & ",Q" & cl.Row & ",R" & cl.Row & ",S" & cl.Row & ",T" & cl.Row & ",U" & cl.Row & ",V" & cl.Row & ",W" & cl.Row).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:="=7" 'apply CF rule to 2 different cells in same row (Separate each cell with , like G2,H2...)
        .Range("I" & cl.Row & ",J" & cl.Row & ",K" & cl.Row & ",L" & cl.Row & ",M" & cl.Row & ",N" & cl.Row & ",O" & cl.Row & ",P" & cl.Row & ",Q" & cl.Row & ",R" & cl.Row & ",S" & cl.Row & ",T" & cl.Row & ",U" & cl.Row & ",V" & cl.Row & ",W" & cl.Row).FormatConditions(2).Interior.Color = RGB(128, 0, 128)
        
        .Range("J" & cl.Row & ",K" & cl.Row & ",L" & cl.Row & ",M" & cl.Row & ",R" & cl.Row & ",S" & cl.Row & ",T" & cl.Row & ",U" & cl.Row).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=5" 'apply CF rule to 2 different cells in same row (Separate each cell with , like G2,H2...)
        .Range("J" & cl.Row & ",K" & cl.Row & ",L" & cl.Row & ",M" & cl.Row & ",R" & cl.Row & ",S" & cl.Row & ",T" & cl.Row & ",U" & cl.Row).FormatConditions(3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 140, 0)
        
        .Range("Z" & cl.Row).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=2" 'apply CF rule to 1 single cell in same row
        .Range("Z" & cl.Row).FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbRed
        
    End If
    If UCase(cl.Value) = "CUCA" Then
        
        .Range("G" & cl.Row & ",H" & cl.Row & ",I" & cl.Row & ",J" & cl.Row & ",K" & cl.Row & ",L" & cl.Row & ",M" & cl.Row & ",N" & cl.Row & ",O" & cl.Row & ",P" & cl.Row & ",Q" & cl.Row & ",R" & cl.Row & ",S" & cl.Row & ",T" & cl.Row & ",U" & cl.Row & ",V" & cl.Row & ",W" & cl.Row & ",X" & cl.Row).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=1" 'apply CF rule to 2 different cells in same row (Separate each cell with , like G2,H2...)
        .Range("G" & cl.Row & ",H" & cl.Row & ",I" & cl.Row & ",J" & cl.Row & ",K" & cl.Row & ",L" & cl.Row & ",M" & cl.Row & ",N" & cl.Row & ",O" & cl.Row & ",P" & cl.Row & ",Q" & cl.Row & ",R" & cl.Row & ",S" & cl.Row & ",T" & cl.Row & ",U" & cl.Row & ",V" & cl.Row & ",W" & cl.Row & ",X" & cl.Row).FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbRed

    End If
    If UCase(cl.Value) = "SERVICE ADMIN" Then
        
        .Range("G" & cl.Row & ",H" & cl.Row & ",I" & cl.Row & ",J" & cl.Row & ",K" & cl.Row & ",L" & cl.Row & ",M" & cl.Row & ",N" & cl.Row & ",O" & cl.Row & ",P" & cl.Row & ",Q" & cl.Row & ",R" & cl.Row & ",S" & cl.Row & ",T" & cl.Row & ",U" & cl.Row & ",V" & cl.Row & ",W" & cl.Row & ",X" & cl.Row).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=1" 'apply CF rule to 2 different cells in same row (Separate each cell with , like G2,H2...)
        .Range("G" & cl.Row & ",H" & cl.Row & ",I" & cl.Row & ",J" & cl.Row & ",K" & cl.Row & ",L" & cl.Row & ",M" & cl.Row & ",N" & cl.Row & ",O" & cl.Row & ",P" & cl.Row & ",Q" & cl.Row & ",R" & cl.Row & ",S" & cl.Row & ",T" & cl.Row & ",U" & cl.Row & ",V" & cl.Row & ",W" & cl.Row & ",X" & cl.Row).FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If
    
    If UCase(cl.Value) = "2ND" Then
        
        .Range("F" & cl.Row & ",G" & cl.Row & ",H" & cl.Row & ",I" & cl.Row & ",J" & cl.Row & ",K" & cl.Row & ",L" & cl.Row & ",M" & cl.Row & ",N" & cl.Row & ",O" & cl.Row & ",P" & cl.Row & ",Q" & cl.Row & ",R" & cl.Row & ",S" & cl.Row & ",T" & cl.Row & ",U" & cl.Row & ",V" & cl.Row & ",W" & cl.Row & ",X" & cl.Row).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=1" 'apply CF rule to 2 different cells in same row (Separate each cell with , like G2,H2...)
        .Range("F" & cl.Row & ",G" & cl.Row & ",H" & cl.Row & ",I" & cl.Row & ",J" & cl.Row & ",K" & cl.Row & ",L" & cl.Row & ",M" & cl.Row & ",N" & cl.Row & ",O" & cl.Row & ",P" & cl.Row & ",Q" & cl.Row & ",R" & cl.Row & ",S" & cl.Row & ",T" & cl.Row & ",U" & cl.Row & ",V" & cl.Row & ",W" & cl.Row & ",X" & cl.Row).FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbRed
    
     End If
     
    If UCase(cl.Value) = "CHAT" Then
        
        .Range("H" & cl.Row & ",I" & cl.Row & ",J" & cl.Row & ",K" & cl.Row & ",L" & cl.Row & ",M" & cl.Row & ",N" & cl.Row & ",O" & cl.Row & ",P" & cl.Row & ",Q" & cl.Row & ",R" & cl.Row & ",S" & cl.Row & ",T" & cl.Row & ",U" & cl.Row & ",V" & cl.Row & ",W" & cl.Row).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=1" 'apply CF rule to 2 different cells in same row (Separate each cell with , like G2,H2...)
        .Range("H" & cl.Row & ",I" & cl.Row & ",J" & cl.Row & ",K" & cl.Row & ",L" & cl.Row & ",M" & cl.Row & ",N" & cl.Row & ",O" & cl.Row & ",P" & cl.Row & ",Q" & cl.Row & ",R" & cl.Row & ",S" & cl.Row & ",T" & cl.Row & ",U" & cl.Row & ",V" & cl.Row & ",W" & cl.Row).FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbRed
                                 
    
    End If
    
Next cl
```

End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub